# 'Page not found' error in Django code while making the pipeline

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an e-commerce website in django.
I want to lay the rough pipeline using this code but when i search, for example- http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/about - This 404 Error come on my screen. Please tell me what to do.

```
 Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/about
 Using the URLconf defined in ekona.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

 admin/
 shop [name='ShopHome']

 shop about [name='about']
 shop contact/ [name='ContactUs']
 shop tracker/ [name='Tracker']
 shop search/ [name='Search']
 shop prodview/ [name='ProdView']
 shop checkout/ [name='Checkout']
 blog
 The current path, shop/about, didn’t match any of these.

 You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that 
 to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

My settings.py is -

```
"""
Django settings for ekona project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-o5!u%!k$n7a)q_wqj$av#t7%xplhhtt1mkefs)(q$*79$b6guq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'shop',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ekona.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ekona.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

My urls.py for this 'shop' page is-

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='ShopHome'),
    path('about', views.about, name='AboutUs'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='ContactUs'),
    path('tracker/', views.tracker, name='Tracker'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='Search'),
    path('prodview/', views.productView, name='ProdView'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='Checkout'),
    
]
```

My views.py for this 'shop' page is-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'shop/index.html')

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at about")

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at contact")

def tracker(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at tracker")

def search(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at search")

def productView(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at product view")

def checkout(request):
    return HttpResponse("We are at checkout")
```

Please tell me why's the error coming

Comment: Can you please share your main urls.py(at the same path with settings.py) file to show how did you include shop app URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ekona.urls add the following:

```
path('shop/', include("shop.urls")),
```

Also, make sure to import **include** like so:

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/about
```

You don't have this url in your urls.py try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
```

without /shop/

edit:
probably you have 2 urls.py files. One in project folder, and one in app folder. In your project urls.py you should add line:

```
path('shop/', include("shop.urls")),
```

and in yout app urls.py add line:

```
app_name = "shop"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the syntax to do add this url?

Comment: If you want "http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/about" you should have "path('shop/about', views.about, name='AboutUs')," in your url patterns

Comment: Thanks, @KamilBaranowskiCZ, but it still isnt working for me :(